# Form is not secure

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-chrome, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

My site has suddenly started showing

> The information that you’re about to submit is not secure

message, even though it is secured with **SSL certificate**, which means it is HTTPS protocol.

I checked this on Firefox and there it worked. But this message comes after each form submission on Google Chrome.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1158169 is a thread related to this issue.  It depends on, among other things, what server your site is using but that thread has several different fixes that may help.

Comment: Can you share the address of the form?

Comment: "address" means? Wherever there is a form tag, on its submission, "The information that you’re about to submit is not secure" message is getting shown.

Answer (score 0):

The instant way to solve the issue is updating the redirect url on your form action function. I am not sure in which language your project is. But I had fixed this in my CakePHP project by adding redirect like this. Maybe it can  help you.

`return $this->redirect("//" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . '/redirectpagename');`

Answer (score 0):

> In my case flask ...
> I add   in wsgi.py file

from core import app

if **name** == '**main**':

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

app.run(host='127.0.0.1',port=5000,debug=True)
```